# 7zip equivalent to "zip -9" for maximum compression?

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, 7-zip

Please forgive my ignorance here. I've read the 7zip man page, and its not clear to me how to achieve the equivalent to `zip -9 ...`. I *think* the man page of interest is [-m (Set compression Method) switch](http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm).

What is the 7zip equivalent to `zip -9 ...` for maximum compression?

---

In the larger picture, [here is how it is being used](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/TestScripts/coverity-windows.txt) on Windows. On Unix, Linux and OS X we use the `zip` command:

```
 7z.exe a -r -tzip cryptopp.zip cov-int
```

Comment: According to that man page it would probably be something like `7z a cryptopp.7z -r -mx=9 cov-int/*`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Use `-mx=9` switch.

As you can see on the manual page you linked, 7z offers you several methods of compression: Copy, Deflate, Deflate64, BZip2, LZMA, PPMd

In paragraph related to each method, you can see whether `x` parameter (setting of compression level) is supported for that method and what levels are valid. You can see that value `9` is generally valid with all methods which support setting of compression level and it represents maximum compression.

So the example is (derived from the manual page):

```
7z a archive.zip *.jpg -mx9
```

(It is a bit strange that they write `-mx9` without `=` in the example. If this does not work, just use `-mx=9`.)

Comment: Behavior changes based on file-type. For `.zip` use with `7z a` the default output size seems the same as using `-mx9`. However this is not true to `.7z` files, and you need to specify `-mx9` for max compression. Btw, both `-mx9` and `-mx=9` work fine.

Comment: The manual page implies that you can compress even *further* than `-mx9` with `7zip`. According to the manual page, `-mx9` is a shortcut for `-mfb=128 -mpass=10`. But it seems like the maximum possible compression levels for .zip and .gz is actually `-mfb=258 -mpass=15`. I see why 7zip doesn't make this more accessible, though - in my use case, passing `-mfb=258 -mpass=15` instead of `-mx=9` gave a super marginal improvement, saving an extra 215KiB on a 514MiB archive of a 2402MiB file (only .004%!)